# Scala interpreter won't start on jupyter notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

Trying to setup Spark Scala on jupyter notebook, using this guide:
https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/how-can-we-run-scala-in-a-jupyter-notebook/td-p/17752

Installing went ok, but when trying this code in a new notebook

```
val x = 2
 
val y = 3
 
x+y
```

running the cell provides no errors but execution is stuck at "Intitializing Scala interpreter ..."